# One webapp, two domain, no redirect. How?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes, localization

I have a Laravel webapp and I want to connect two domain for it.
`myApp.com` and `myApp.hu`

I want to reach that if I come from myApp.com it startes with the browser's locale and if it isn't supported (for example it's German) it uses the English localisation. But if I come from myApp.hu it works like is in the previous example, but it will uses hungarian as the 'fallback language'.

Next to it I want to use the URL as it comes.

For example if I comes from the myApp.com the /about will be `myApp.com/about`.
But if I going from the myApp.hu the about page's route will drop me to the `myApp.hu/about`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `$request` object to get the current host name.

```
$request->getHttpHost() // returns myApp.com or myApp.hu
```

From that, handle your `app()->setLocale()` depending on the domain extension and you're all set !